# MacBook Pro randomly crashes when not plugged in, how to find the cause?

Tags: macos, crash, macbook

My MacBook Pro crashes randomly when not plugged in.

I can not find the cause of the problem.

After restarting, I saw this error report, which I unfortunately don't understand.

I have macOS Sierra Beta, but it also happened with previous OS X.

```
Anonymous UUID:       9EA55F1E-9D93-8F4E-49CB-ACE8B9E5F50E

Sun Jul 31 11:06:05 2016

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff800760d23a): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f880a42c7, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000000000000000, CR3: 0x0000000009907000, CR4: 0x00000000001627e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0x000000000000005b, RCX: 0x000000000005000e, RDX: 0x0000000000000001
RSP: 0xffffff922282bb40, RBP: 0xffffff922282bb40, RSI: 0xffffff80349191b0, RDI: 0xffffff8034919000
R8:  0x000000000000ffff, R9:  0x0000000000000001, R10: 0xffffff803fbdb3e0, R11: 0x0000000000000000
R12: 0xffffff8034919000, R13: 0xffffff8026237000, R14: 0xffffff7f880c4b18, R15: 0xffffff8034919000
RFL: 0x0000000000010246, RIP: 0xffffff7f880a42c7, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000000, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x0, PL: 0

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff922282b7d0 : 0xffffff80074fb47c 
0xffffff922282b850 : 0xffffff800760d23a 
0xffffff922282ba30 : 0xffffff80074ad743 
0xffffff922282ba50 : 0xffffff7f880a42c7 
0xffffff922282bb40 : 0xffffff7f880a4186 
0xffffff922282bb70 : 0xffffff7f880a5e28 
0xffffff922282bbd0 : 0xffffff7f880a494a 
0xffffff922282bc40 : 0xffffff7f880a0e56 
0xffffff922282bcd0 : 0xffffff8007abf5fa 
0xffffff922282bd40 : 0xffffff7f8809fcee 
0xffffff922282be10 : 0xffffff7f8809f73b 
0xffffff922282bee0 : 0xffffff7f87fe3036 
0xffffff922282bf00 : 0xffffff80075327ba 
0xffffff922282bfb0 : 0xffffff80074aaaf7 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily(1.1)[4C2B8509-E3FC-3B81-86F1-7F609F616C5F]@0xffffff7f87fde000->0xffffff7f88045fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController(1.0)[7510E536-1A0A-3F42-A8EE-ADCF8A74884D]@0xffffff7f87fd1000
         com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily(900.4.1)[C90F1DCB-956B-321D-BCD3-25C245CFD19F]@0xffffff7f8804e000->0xffffff7f880e7fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[CAEDB4BD-1C1D-375C-A364-5BFB512B41F0]@0xffffff7f87d30000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily(1.1)[4C2B8509-E3FC-3B81-86F1-7F609F616C5F]@0xffffff7f87fde000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
16A238m

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 16.0.0: Tue Jun 28 15:57:40 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3757.0.0.0.1~20/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 9E7D2B4B-1F72-3431-82DA-B4E320BF6642
Kernel slide:     0x0000000007200000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8007400000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8007300000
System model name: MacBookPro11,1 (Mac-189A3D4F975D5FFC)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 16886869705245
last loaded kext at 16886157644400: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   900.4.1 (addr 0xffffff7f8927b000, size 12288)
last unloaded kext at 14224446241824: com.apple.driver.usb.cdc  5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f8927b000, size 28672)
loaded kexts:
com.getdropbox.dropbox.kext 1.7.4
com.parallels.virtualhid    1.0.3 3
com.techsmith.TACC  1.0.3
com.parallels.virtualsound  1.0.36 36
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.1
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    5.0.0d76
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.7
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000Graphics   10.1.8
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   276.00
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.9.10
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferAzul  10.1.8
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 5.0.0d76
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1100.33.1a2
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    208
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface   5.54.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.13
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 403
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  251
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 251
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 38
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  362
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  294
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  325
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   166
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   149
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 276.00
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 276.00
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 276.00
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.13.53
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    274
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   5.0.0d76
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  5.0.0d76
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   5.0.0d76
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.14d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   205.9
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   394
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  130
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   394
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 258
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.1
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    535
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    288
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.5.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.5.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.1.6
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 442
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  5.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro11,1, BootROM MBP111.0138.B17, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2,6 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.16f68
Graphics: Intel Iris, Intel Iris, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533641465238412D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533641465238412D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x112), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.167.2.1a2)
Bluetooth: Version 5.0.0d76, 3 services, 17 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0512F, 500,28 GB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: External USB 3.0
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 17.2
```

Comment: This is almost definitely a hardware problem...

Comment: @Rahul2001 Is there a "simple" way to find out which hardware is causing the problem?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this YouTube channel: https://www.youtube.com/user/rossmanngroup - He has some pretty good videos and I think he has a one regarding this issue too...